# Get parent category for product page Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

is there a way to get the parent category of a product, in the product page for Opencart? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can.
I've tested my code in OpenCart 1.5.1.x

First, you must modify the file /catalog/controller/product/product.php to add 
after the line 94: 
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

ADD this:

`$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_info['product_id']);
if ($categories){
$categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
$this->data['category_id'] = $categories_info['category_id'];
}`

Then, you can use the variable `<?php echo $category_id ?>` in your template file (product.tpl).

Hope this help you