# Opencart 2.1.0.1 change Related Products title if a certain Parent Category

Tags: opencart, categories, product

I have been having several issues with what I think would be simple workarounds logically.

For this case, I have a client that wants the Related Products section on the product page to say "Spare Parts" if that product is under the Equipment parent category and "Related Products" for everything else.

In my product.tpl file, I have inserted the following if statement:

```
<div class="box-heading"> 

    <?php
    if (isset($category_id) && ($category_id == '59' || $category_id == '106' || $category_id == '86' ) ) { ?>
        Spare Parts
    <?php } else { ?>
        Related Products
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

I had success on the statement working when I specifically targeted the product ID but in this case there are so many products it wouldn't make any sense to target by product. I really need to be able to target the Equipment product category specifically and have the if statement apply to all sub categories under that parent category.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883105/get-parent-category-for-product-page-opencart

Comment: I can help you. The procedure is a bit lengthy.

Comment: That's fine I appreciate the help